# combining many data frames with rbind and pages

Tags: r, rbind, jsonlite

I am trying to rbind pages sequentially by combining the data frames using the pages.

```
library(jsonlite)
pages <- list()
for(i in 1:3){
mydata<- data.frame(c(1,2), c(4,5))
pages[[i+1]] <- mydata$filings
}
filings <- rbind.pages(pages)
```

When i view the filings dataset I see only 0 variables. I am expecting 6 rows and 2 columns. Can some one address how to tether and attach the data while looping. Thanks

Comment: i tried but it didn't work!

Comment: I have made the changes to the code. Now it is reproducible

Comment: It is not reproducible because `rbind.pages` is not a function, as far as I know.

Comment: You refer to the `filings` column (`mydata$filings`) which is undefined

Comment: I used the code from jsonlite package page 4.