# rbind.pages with missing pages "Error: all(vapply(pages, is.data.frame, logical(1)))" is not TRUE

Tags: json, r, rjsonio, jsonlite

I am trying to rbind.pages with jsonlite from web where some of the data files are missing(for example values for aa are missing).

```
temp<- c("6702","1","67")
library(jsonlite)
baseurl <- "https://api.angel.co/1/startups/"
pages <- list()
for(i in 1:3){
  mydata<- fromJSON(paste0(baseurl,temp[[i]]),flatten= TRUE)
 pages[[i+1]] <- mydata
}
out<- rbind.pages(pages[sapply(pages, length)>2])
```

I am getting the following errors. Any suggestions on how to address this? Thanks.

```
Error: Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 404.
Error: all(vapply(pages, is.data.frame, logical(1))) is not TRUE
```

Comment: Just like with your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30539282/combining-many-data-frames-with-rbind-and-pages), we need a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Am I allowed to specify external urls/api link?

Comment: When are you doing `pages[[i+1]] <- mydata` rather than `pages[[i]] <- mydata`? You shound't have `NULL` items in the list for `rbind.pages()` to work

Comment: Exactly i don't know when i am getting null values. So is there a way i can handle them so i can attach using rbind. I tried the code you mentioned it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rbind.pages` doesn't appear to like "empty" lists. You should filter your list to exclude them

```
out<- rbind.pages(pages[sapply(pages, length)>0])
```

Comment: it worked but as i running others i am getting an http error and it is stopping the looping operation. Any suggestions? I am editing the data points for reproducibility.